# Visual Studio Code Language and Terminal Language

Tags: terminal, language, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode for ASP.NET Core. I have an issue about display and terminal language.

My computer language is in Turkish, VSCode language is in English.

When I'm debugging the project, as you see in the picture, I'm getting the errors in Turkish. But I want to get in English and also I do not want to change my computer language. How to set up this?

[image: VSCode ScreenShot]]